# CSS: How to I exclude a DIV and its descendents?

Tags: css, jquery-selectors

I have html that looks like this:

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <div id="childDiv1">
        <img />
        <div>
            <img />
            <div />
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
    <div id="childDiv2">
        ...
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to select everything in mainDiv except childDiv1 and its descendents.  I thought that `#mainDiv :not(#childDiv1)` might work but it only excludes `chidlDiv1` while all of its descendents get selected. `#childDiv1 *` will select all of the descendents (but not childDiv1 itself) but `:not(#childDiv1 *)` is invalid.
A jQuery solution would be preferable.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think this works:

```
$("#mainDiv > :not(#childDiv1)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#mainDiv :not(#childDiv1), #childDiv :not(*)")
```

Answer (score 0):

if any mainDiv children is in div format.

```
$('#mainDiv div:gt(0)')
```